# Order by in SQL when the values have String and Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012

I have values in 'name' column like this

```
AMOU
VHOR
1A
7W1
11W
12W
```

and I am using this query to sort them in order

`select * from Unit c where expsetid=382 order by CONVERT(INT,substring(name, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name+'z'))) asc`

When I order by desc I got

```
12W
11W
7W1
1A
AMOU
VHOR
```

But I expect them to be in this order when its desc

```
12W
11W
7W1
1A
VHOR
AMOU
```

Comment: What database are you using

Comment: Consult [Complex sort of field "string - number - string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461619/).

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Erm what order do they come out in when you order by asc...

Comment: @DourHighArch the link you gave its not behaving as expected eigther

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I expect the last list when its desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `0` as the start index for `substring`, which should instead be `1`.

When you use zero, you actually get an empty string that is being converted to 0 and thus ordering the alpha strings first. When you use 1, you correctly get an conversion to int error.

Comment: I got error when I used '1' "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '11W' to data type int."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me in finding the solution as I expected. Here is the query which work for my situation.

```
select * from Unit c 
where expsetid=382
order by Row_Number() over (Order By CONVERT(INT,substring(name, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name+'z')))) desc
```