# order by string field with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm selecting customer orders and i order them by customer_name.

The customer names are interesting, they go something like this

- A Customer
- A Customer #1
- A Customer #2
- Some customer #1
- Some customer #2
- Some customer #10
- Some customer #11

when I write the following query

```
select customer_name from orders order by customer_name
```

This is what I get

- A Customer
- A Customer #1
- A Customer #2
- Some customer #1
- Some customer #10
- Some customer #11
- Some customer #2

Notice that - Some customer #2 goes after - Some customer #11

[I found this post which says to do the following:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461619/complex-sort-of-field-string-number-string)

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN customer_name not like '%[0-9]%' THEN customer_name ELSE
   STUFF(customer_name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',customer_name), 0, replicate('0', 
   PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',customer_name) - len(customer_name) + PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',reverse(customer_name)) + 6))
END
```

Is there a better way to order by the numbers at the end?

Comment: The better way would be to stuff those numbers into another column and order by that... otherwise you're stuck parsing the string.

Comment: @paqogomez You are on the right track, but putting the numbers alone in another field won't work as the part of the name to the left of the number still needs to sort correctly. It really needs to be the whole thing (or split out the name part by itself as well, but that just seems more complicated than beneficial).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense @srutzky.  `Order by newNumberColumn, customer_name` not work for you?

Comment: @paqogomez I haven't tried it, but by definition it can't work. Customer numbers overlap. Look at the sample data: "A Customer #2" and "Some Customer #2" would then sort on the "2" first, and _then_ on the "A Customer" and "Some Customer". Then, both of those, if having a #3, would sort those next. This scheme would interweave the string values within the same numbers.

Comment: @srutzky, nope, you are correct. I think i was too asleep when I read your comment this morning.  Parsing the string as you and Gordon have done is the only good way.

Answer (score 2):

If all the numbers start with `'#'`, then you can do:

```
order by (case when customer_name not like '%#%' then customer_name
               else left(customer_name, charindex('#', customer_name))
          end),
         len(customer_name),
         customer_name
```

You could fiddle with trying to extract the number at the end of the string, if it exists, but given the formats in your question, this should work.

Comment: This doesn't even come close to working. Anyone who reads this and knows anything about SQL should be able to tell without even testing it. And clearly it wasn't tested. Doesn't it seem odd that _only_ answer here that _doesn't_ work (the other 3 do) is somehow the _only_ answer to have any upvotes?

Comment: @srutzky . . . If you were referring to the missing `not` in the `case` condition, then, yes, your were correct.  (Copy and paste error.)  But in this case, the code has actually been tested, and it does work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two part answer :)

### First: Getting the Sorting Right

The first thing to do is find a way to normalize the company_name values that have a "#". Since this is a string field it is going to sort numbers based on their position, not based on their value. So rather than split this value into multiple fields to put into an `ORDER BY`, let's make the string representation of the customer number something that *is* sortable. Meaning, while "2" naturally comes after "10" in terms of them being strings, "02" comes *before* "10", as expected. Take a look-see at the following:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

-- DROP TABLE #Orders
CREATE TABLE #Orders
(
  OrderID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  CustomerName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('A Customer');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('A Customer #1');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('A Customer #2');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('Some customer #1');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('Some customer #2');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('Some customer #10');
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerName) VALUES ('Some customer #11');


SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN CustomerName LIKE N'%#%' THEN
           STUFF(
                 [CustomerName],
                 (CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName]) + 1), -- start just after the "#"
                 0, -- don't overwrite anything
                 REPLICATE(N'0',
                        (6 - (LEN([CustomerName]) - CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName])))
                          ) -- ensure 6 digits
                )
            ELSE [CustomerName]
       END AS [SortName-test]
FROM #Orders
ORDER BY [SortName-test];
```

The results are as you desire.

### Second: How / Where to Implement This

Sure, you *could* always just put this expression in the `ORDER BY` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Orders
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN CustomerName LIKE N'%#%' THEN
           STUFF(
                 [CustomerName],
                 (CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName]) + 1), -- start just after the "#"
                 0, -- don't overwrite anything
                 REPLICATE(N'0',
                        (6 - (LEN([CustomerName]) - CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName])))
                          ) -- ensure 6 digits
                )
            ELSE [CustomerName]
       END;
```

But, depending on the size of the table and how often this field will be used in an `ORDER BY` (or even a `GROUP BY` or any other operation requiring a sort), doing an on-the-fly manipulation can be quite costly, and it can't be indexed.

In that case, it can be added as a `PERSISTED COMPUTED COLUMN`. Since it is "computed" it will change appropriately with any changes to the value in the base `[company_name]` field. And since it is "persisted", a) the value will be there and can even be used by the Query Optimizer, and b) it can be indexed for even more betterness.

Just run:

```
ALTER TABLE #Orders ADD [SortName] AS (CASE WHEN CustomerName LIKE N'%#%' THEN
           STUFF(
                 [CustomerName],
                 (CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName]) + 1), -- start just after the "#"
                 0, -- don't overwrite anything
                 REPLICATE(N'0',
                        (6 - (LEN([CustomerName]) - CHARINDEX(N'#', [CustomerName]))))
                          ) -- ensure 6 digits
            ELSE [CustomerName]
       END) PERSISTED;
```

And that leaves you with the uber-complicated query of:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Orders
ORDER BY [SortName];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break customer name in two pieces: Preceding string, trailing number and order by string, number.

See this:

```
SELECT *, LEFT(customer_name, LEN(customer_name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  REVERSE(customer_name) )),
          RIGHT(customer_name, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  REVERSE(customer_name) ))
FROM @Orders
ORDER BY LEFT(customer_name, LEN(customer_name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  REVERSE(customer_name) )),
         CAST(RIGHT(customer_name, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  REVERSE(customer_name) )) AS INT)
```

The above will work even if there is no '#' inside customer_name and even if there is another number inside customer_name, e.g. with `Customer 12`, `Jonn 2 Smith #12` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simple way would be

```
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN customer_name NOT LIKE '%#%' THEN '0'
            WHEN customer_name LIKE '%#%' THEN LEFT(customer_name, Len(customer_name) - Charindex('#', customer_name))
          END,
          RIGHT(customer_name, Len(customer_name) - Charindex('#', customer_name))
```